# Which design pattern should I use for console rasing sim?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I need to make a console racing simulator using gof (or other) design patterns, but I don't know which one to use here.

I already made the game, but it's more like "OOP for the sake of OOP style". It has a Car class which contains drive, control and gameover methods and and Obstacle class, which generates and moves an obstacles.

Which design pattern should I use to make the game? Can I recomposit existing classes or must I start it all from scratch?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Code > Text. Show some code! Also, what does "but it's more like "OOP for the sake of OOP style" really mean?

Comment: Why does your `Car` class have *control and gameover methods and an Obstacle method, which generates and moves an obstacles*? None of those seem to be car-related. The core idea is to model objects in code like they are in the real world. Real cars don't generate and move obstacles, so your `Car` shouldn't either. That way it becomes much more obvious and predictable what stuff does because we have some intuitive understanding of cars and other real world objects.

Comment: I really don't won't to make refactoring, application works pretty fine and code is kinda clean and readable.The thing is that it is my test task, and using of design patterns is one of the conditions.
Here's the code [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/ym3q74r2nhkvf2n/ConsoleApplication9.cpp?dl=0

Comment: npw, I meant Obstacle class, sorry for misspealing

Comment: So you want to move from "OOP for the sake of OOP" to "design pattern for the sake of design pattern"?

Comment: definitely yes.

Comment: design patterns on their own are completely useless (exaggeration intended ;). You use design patterns to get something done. If you have already something working and then applying design patterns is like first building a house and only then asking an architect how you should layout the foundations in such a way that it will be easy to build

Comment: Okay, so if the case is not to refactor the code, but to write it from scratch, which design pattern is better for racing simulator?